# What can you conclude about $A \setminus B = B \setminus A$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have the following identity involving sets $A$ and $B$:

$$A \setminus B = B \setminus A$$

Now, a solution says that we can conclude that $A=B$, but what is wrong with a solution that says that this means that $A\subseteq B$? I mean if we remove all elements of $B$ from $A$, we would have what is left from $B$ and same for if we remove all elements of $A$ from $B$ as it will yield also elements of $B$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: $A-B=B-A$ does indeed imply that $A\subseteq B$... It also implies that $B\subseteq A$ by the same logic.  Both of these together imply $A=B$.  "*What is wrong with a solution that says this?*"  Nothing is incorrect, however it is woefully incomplete with almost no additional effort required.

Comment: Please use "\setminus" if you want to write the insiemistic difference

Comment: @Gabrielek I also prefer $\setminus$, but $-$ is commonly used to denote the set-theoretic difference. On the other hand, the word "insiemistic" is totally unfamiliar to me.

Comment: You don't give much context for the question, but $A=B$ is a stronger statement.

Comment: @JMoravitz. Thanks! So the same argument in the question above should be done for the other side of the set identity to complete the analysis and get that $A=B$?

Comment: Sorry, my bad use of italianized english. I meant "Set theory"

Comment: "If we remove all elements of $B$ from $A$, we would have what is left from $B$". No, if $A\subseteq B$ and we remove all elements of $B$ from $A$, we are left with nothing: $A\setminus B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation reads: "If $x$ is in $A$ but not $B$, then $x$ is also in $B$ but not $A$

The set of elements which can be seen as inside and not inside an arbitrary set $A$ simultaneously is $\emptyset$.

Hence $$A\setminus B=\emptyset \implies A=B$$

Comment: $\emptyset$ is not an element here. There are no elements satisfying the requirements, so the set of elements that satisfy the requirements is the empty set.

Comment: Quite.  The correct wording should have been "*There exist no elements which can be seen as inside and not inside an arbitrary set $A$ simultaneously*"

Comment: "The only element which can be seen as inside and not inside an arbitrary set $A$ simultaneously is $\emptyset$." What? This is nonsense.

Comment: Good points. My bad

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $A\cap B = (A\cup B) \setminus [(A\setminus B) \cup ( B\setminus A) ]=  \begin{cases} (A\cup B) \setminus (A\setminus B) = B \\
(A\cup B) \setminus (B\setminus A) = A\end{cases} $

But this can be true if and only if $A=B$

Answer (score 0):

I think the following answer is more clear:

If $A-B \neq \emptyset$, then since $A-B \subseteq B-A$, there exists an $x \in A$ such that $x \notin A$, a contradiction.

Hence $B-A=A-B = \emptyset$.

If $A = \emptyset$, then $B = \emptyset$ and vice versa which implies the result.

Otherwise, $(x \in A \implies x\in B) \implies A\subseteq B$.

Similarly, one finds that $B \subseteq A$, and so $A=B$.

Comment: I have serious difficulties to follow your steps. "If a set is not empty ... Then it is empty. Then both are the empty set. If one is the empty set, then also the other is.. otherwise one is a subset.. "

Comment: The first part we arrive at a contradiction if $A-B$ is nonempty by taking some arbitrary element $A-B$. This means that $A-B$ must be the empty set. Now there is a "subargument" where I have the cases $A = \emptyset$ or $A \neq \emptyset$. The $A = \emptyset$ case is trivial. I show that either both are empty or both are nonempty.

Comment: Since $A-B = \emptyset$, $x\in A$ and $x \notin B$ is not possible. So then for arbitrary $x \in A$, we must have the implication above. The same argument goes for $x \in B$, since $B$ is nonempty is well in this case.

Comment: I made this argument because I don't quite think $A-B = \emptyset \implies A=B $ follows immediately as the accepted answer suggests.